# Run a Google Script on a Spreadsheet in Drive using Drive API

Tags: google-drive-api

I have a web app for which most new users are importing hostorical data from another platform. The other platform exports the data as an Excel spreadsheet. I need to clean up the spreadsheet and export it as JSON (or csv) so I can import it into my app.

To accomplish this, I have created a service where users can upload an Excel spreadsheet to my Drive, which is then converted to a Google Spreadsheet. I have written a Google Script called Cleanup.gc that also resides in my Drive, which cleans up the data and performs some operations on it.

So far, I am able to upload the user spreadsheets automatically using the Drive API. When the upload completes, it sends back an ID from which the spreadsheet can be identified.

What I would like to do at this point is call the Cleanup.gc script via the appropriate API so that it is executed on the newly uploaded spreadsheet. Once this has completed, I would then proceed with importing the data into my app.

I have looked through many pages of Google API documentation, but I have not found anything that does what I am describing. Does this functionality exist? If not, is there perhaps an intelligent way to use Google Script triggers to accomplish the same thing?

Here is the code I currently have, which runs in the user's browser:

```
var token; //pre-generated Google Auth token passed from server
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("POST", 'https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v2/files?uploadType=media&convert=true', true);
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token);
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/vnd.ms-excel');
        xhr.onload = function() {
            if (xhr.status === 200) {
                var id = xhr.response.id;
                // NOW I NEED TO CALL MY .gc SCRIPT ON THIS ID
            };
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a solution, buried in the very last section of the apps-script API documentation, under 'REST execution API'.

The solution is to use:

```
POST https://script.googleapis.com/v1/scripts/{scriptId}:run
```

You can pass the id of the sheet in the parameters array of the POST request body.
Here is a link to the [page in the documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/execution/rest/v1/scripts/run).

**UPDATE**

And [another link that describes the same thing](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/rest/api#using_the_api_in_an_application). Note that you will have to publish your script as an API executable from within Google Drive before you can call it with the API.

Comment: an easier way without oauth is to publish the other script as an anonymous service